# C++ comparing two char to validate loop conditions

Tags: c++, pointers, comparison

I have created a structure to hold creature information, I use a variable of type char to hold the type of creature it is (A:Aphid, L:Ladybird).

```
struct Creatures {
    int xco;
    int yco;
    char type;
    struct Creatures *next;
};
extern struct Creatures *creatureHead;
extern struct Creatures *creatureTail;
```

When I add a "creature", I include a parameter to identify the type of creature it is. I also have commented out lines that check that the value is passed properly (it is).

```
struct Creatures* add_Creature(int xcoord,int ycoord,char ctype) {
    struct Creatures *ptr = new Creatures;
    ptr -> xco = xcoord;
    ptr -> yco = ycoord;
    //cout << "ctype: " << ctype << endl;
    ptr -> type = ctype;
    //cout << "type: " << ptr->type << endl;
    ptr -> next = NULL;
    if (creatureHead == NULL) {
        creatureHead = creatureTail = ptr;
    }
    else {
        creatureTail -> next = ptr;
        creatureTail = ptr;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

The following is an example of me adding a creature:

```
add_Creature(xco,yco,'A');
```

I then use the following method to print out a table of all Aphids and Ladybirds, at the moment it outputs nothing and I'm not sure why:

```
void printStuff() {
    struct Creatures *ptr = new Creatures;
    cout << "============" << endl;
    cout << "Aphid Coords" << endl;
    cout << "============" << endl;
    while(ptr != NULL && (ptr->type == 'A')) {
        cout << "[" << ptr->xco << "][" << ptr->yco << "]" << endl;
    ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    cout << "============" << endl << endl;
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    cout << "===============" << endl;
    cout << "Ladybird Coords" << endl;
    cout << "===============" << endl;
    while(ptr != NULL && (ptr->type == 'L')) {
        cout << "[" << ptr->xco << "][" << ptr->yco << "]" << endl;
    ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    cout << "===============" << endl;
}
```

Why doesn't the while loop in my print method validate and print out the proper results?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if I'm missing something, but I dont see any initialization of the `ptr` pointer that you declare inside your `printStuff` function, so it may not be `null` but the "type" field may not equals 'A' either.

Comment: Thank you, your comment made me actually re-think my design.. I was meant to initialise the pointer to `creatureHead`

it's all working now, I was just incredibly dense..

I'll close this question!